# Chrome Developer Tools: non-case-sensitive search

Tags: google-chrome, search, case-sensitive

Can Developer Tools in Chrome perform a non-case-sensitive search?

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome always performs a case-insensitive search when you press CTRL+F (Windows) or CMD+F (Mac) when in developer tools.

Comment: Dunno if it's a bug or what, but this is untrue in Chrome v.32. Definitely is case sensitive.

Comment: It depends where you're searching. If you're in the elements panel, it's case insensitive. In the sources panel, it's case insensitive. Where is it showing case sensitivity for you?

Comment: It was case sensitive in the elements panel. This was a bug that was resolved in v33 (I grabbed the beta just to get around it).